# If a group is product of two subgroups, than it's product of the conjugate of the subgroups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I have to prove that:

If $G$ is a group and $H$, $K$ are subgroups of $G$ such that $G=HK$, then $G=H^xK^y$ for every $x, y$ in $G$, where $H^x$ is the conjugate of the subgroup $H$ with respect to $x$. (Same for $K^y$).

I've tried, but i don't really know how to prove it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: Some algebraic manipulation of the elements and things like $x=hk$ for some $h, k$, but ended up concluding nothing.

Comment: It would be useful if you edited something concrete into the question. It already has one vote to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[I write $g^x:=x^{-1}gx$. If you mean $g^x=xgx^{-1}$ then the proofs below need altered accordingly. Doing so is an easy exercise.]

This is best approached in two steps:

1. Prove that $G=H^xK$ for all $x\in G$.
2. Use step 1 to prove the whole result.

Firstly, note that if $h\in H$ then $H^h=H$. Similarly, if $k\in K$ then $K^k=K$.

For step 1, fix $x\in G$ arbitrary. By assumption, there exists $h\in H$ and $k\in K$ such that $x=hk$. Therefore, $$H^xK=H^{hk}K=(H^h)^k=H^kK.$$ As $H^kK$ is conjugate to $HK=G$, we have that $H^xK=G$ as required.

For step 2, fix $x, y\in G$ arbitrary. Then $H^xK^y$ is conjugate to $H^{xy^{-1}}K$. The result then follows from step 1.

Comment: Why would anyone write $g^x = xgx^{-1}$? That would give $g^{(xy)} = (g^y)^x$.